# PDF to PNG from iMagick is very bad quality

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I am converting PDF files to PNG files using imagick in PHP. 
For this example I have a PDF file with only 5 lines of text on the first (and only) page. This PDF is generated from a Word file (it's not scanned in).

My code to convert the file looks like this:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(200,200);
$im->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/codeigniter/vrm/documents/uploaded_documents/2020/04/buddy_voor_lennert-01042020130414.pdf[0]');
$im->scaleImage(500,500);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/codeigniter/vrm/documents/images/thumbnails/lennert.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

After this, the png is created, but the quality of the text is horrible, it becomes unreadable, see the screenshot i attached below.

How do I retain the same quality? I want to generate a thumbnail and a normal size image. So the thumbnail can be of lower quality, but the normal size image should be at least of a readable quality.

I've tried putting the resolution down to 50x50 or tried using the following methods, to no avail:

```
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(0); (also to 100)
$im->resizeImage(500, 500, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0, true);
```

[image: quality png]

Comment: Try increasing your input resolution from 200 to 600.

Comment: Your PDF appears to have at least 100 characters of text per line, as well as spaces between the words. You're resizing the image to be 500pixels wide. Exactly what quality are you expecting here?